# Transfer files from server to server from urls in a text file

Tags: php, text, server, transfer

Hi I want to transfer files from one server to another from urls that are kept in a text file. I'm using a shared linux hosting. 
Currently this code is working for transfering files from a single url. But I want to load many urls from a text file.

```
/* Source File URL */
$remote_file_url = 'http://origin-server-url/files.mp4';

/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = 'files.mp4';

/* Copy the file from source url to server */
$copy = copy( $remote_file_url, $local_file );

/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !$copy ) {
echo "Doh! failed to copy $file...\n";
}
else{
echo "WOOT! success to copy $file...\n";
}
```

And the file name and extension  should be masked from each url.
can somebody help.

Comment: You have to create a array and use foreach

Comment: Can you show me how to do it

Comment: Read each line in the text file one by one and parse it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple example how you could do this.

```
    $remoteFileUrls = [
        'File 1' => 'http://origin-server-url/files.mp4',
        'File 2' => 'http://origin-server-url/files.mp4',
        'File 3' => 'http://origin-server-url/files.mp4',
        'File 4' => 'http://origin-server-url/files.mp4'
    ];

    $localFileUrls = [
        'File 1' => 'files.mp4',
        'File 2' => 'files.mp4',
        'File 3' => 'files.mp4',
        'File 4' => 'files.mp4'
    ];

    foreach($remoteFileUrls as $key => $remoteUrl){
        /* Copy the file from source url to server */
        $copy = copy( $remoteUrl, $localFileUrls[$key] );

        /* Add notice for success/failure */
        if( $copy ) {
            echo "Success\n";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failed\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about dozens of urls, which would be in a text file.

Comment: In that case you haven't provided enough information regarding the issue. There has to be some kind of a structure. In any case you are stuck to using arrays. How you populate those arrays with info is a whole another story